# What is the difference between texture filtering and texture sampling?

Tags: graphics

Are these concepts one and the same? I've seen them used in multiple contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Texture sampling is the act of retrieving data from a texture. Texture filtering is the algorithm by which a pixel or group of pixels within the texture are fetched (and possibly combined) in order to produce the result of a sampling of a texture.

Answer (score 1):

Some links for you:

http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,1155163,00.asp
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/archive/2009/09/08/texture-filtering.aspx